# Column 'Pay_records.ActualTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the TimeCodeTotal per TimeCode.  SQL Server doesn't like my current setup and wants me to add PR.Actual time to the GROUP BY.

This is not a solution because adding PR.ActualTime to the GROUP BY changes the results to incorrect values;
 I only want to GROUP BY the values provided in the query below.

Is there another way to seperate by timecode without using the OVER (BY PARTITION) clause?

```
SELECT YEAR(PR.date) AS TimeYear
    ,SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,MONTH(PR.Date),0)- 1),1,3) AS TimeMonth
    ,TC.TimeCode
    ,SUM(PR.ActualTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.TimeCode) AS TimeCodeTotal
    ,SUM(PR.ActualTime) AS MonthTotal
    FROM Pay_records PR
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.employee_no = PR.employee_no
INNER JOIN Dept_Names D ON D.Dept = E.department
INNER JOIN DepartmentTimeCategory DTC ON DTC.Dept = D.Dept
INNER JOIN TimeCategory TMC ON TMC.ID = DTC.TimeCategoryID
INNER JOIN TimeCode TC ON TC.TimeCodeID = TMC.TimeCodeID
WHERE PR.DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '02/17/16'
AND D.Dept IN ('02Z103')
AND E.Billable IN (1,0)
GROUP BY  YEAR(PR.date), MONTH(PR.date), TC.TimeCode
ORDER BY YEAR(PR.date), MONTH(PR.date)
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? I think I know how to fix this, but it would help to have some data to confirm.

Comment: @JoeRandel does the existing answer fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy fix is to remove `SUM(PR.ActualTime) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.TimeCode) AS TimeCodeTotal` from the query, wrap the whole thing in a CTE, and then select everything from the CTE and add a `SUM(TimeCodeTotal)`.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT      YEAR(PR.date) AS TimeYear 
                ,SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,MONTH(PR.Date),0)- 1),1,3) AS TimeMonth 
                ,TC.TimeCode 
                ,SUM(PR.ActualTime) AS TimeCodeSubTotal 

    FROM        Pay_records             PR 
    INNER JOIN  Employee                E       ON E.employee_no = PR.employee_no 
    INNER JOIN  Dept_Names              D       ON D.Dept = E.department 
    INNER JOIN  DepartmentTimeCategory  DTC     ON DTC.Dept = D.Dept 
    INNER JOIN  TimeCategory            TMC     ON TMC.ID = DTC.TimeCategoryID 
    INNER JOIN  TimeCode                TC      ON TC.TimeCodeID = TMC.TimeCodeID

    WHERE       PR.DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '02/17/16' 
    AND         D.Dept IN ('02Z103') 
    AND         E.Billable IN (1,0) 

    GROUP BY    YEAR(PR.date)
                ,MONTH(PR.date)
                ,TC.TimeCode 
    ) 
SELECT      TimeYear
            , TimeMonth
            , TimeCode
            , TimeCodeSubTotal 
            , Sum(TimeCodeSubTotal) 

FROM        CTE

GROUP BY    TimeYear
            , TimeMonth
            , TimeCode
            , TimeCodeSubTotal 

ORDER BY    YEAR(PR.date)
            , MONTH(PR.date)
```

Comment: I have just submitted an edit request that adds the content of your comments to the actual answer. Hopefully peer review will accept it :) Since the SQL was missing formatting, I have applied the indentation/layout I would use: I hope that is OK. Perhaps you'll be able to edit it further now, if you wish.